# Remote management issues

Tags: windows-firewall, hyper-v-server-2012, remote-access

I have HyperV Server 2012 R2 installed and I've opened ports in the firewall to allow remote snapins to connect.  They mostly work, but, for example, the logical  disk manager connects and shows information, but refreshing doesn't work.  I get no errors from the snap-in but I can only see updates by closing and reopening the console.

I see this error in the event log of the server.

`Event filter with query "SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 10 WHERE (TargetInstance ISA 'Msvm_ExternalEthernetPort') OR (TargetInstance ISA 'Msvm_VmLANEndpoint') OR (TargetInstance ISA 'Msvm_SyntheticEthernetPort') OR (TargetInstance ISA 'Msvm_ComputerSystem') OR (TargetInstance ISA 'Msvm_VLANEndpointSettingData')" could not be reactivated in namespace "//./root/virtualization" because of error 0x80041010. Events cannot be delivered through this filter until the problem is corrected.`

Any ideas?

Comment: from what system are You connecting to manage this 2012 R2 ? Win7 Win8 Win8.1 another 2012R2 ?

Comment: @BartłomiejZarzecki Windows 8.1 Pro and Windows 8 Pro, both have the same issue.

Comment: I noticed the same problem from win8/win8.1. I also noticed that connecting from windows 2008 R2 works OK.